# lxml.tostring incorrectly replacing text with HTML entities

Tags: python, html, xml, lxml

I am currently taking strings from YAML files and converting them to XML. I'm using `lxml.etree` to do this and am essentially building a single XML tag `<msg>` for each value in my YAML file and then writing it out using `lxml.etree.tostring()`. However, the files given to me occasionally have HTML tags such as `<a>`, HTML entities such as `&nbsp;`, as well as character likes `&`. The LXML parser is currently converting all of these to HTML entities so that `<a>` becomes `&lt;a&gt;` and `&nbsp;` becomes `&amp;nbsp;` and `&` simply becomes `&amp;`.

In the first two cases it appears like I'll lose that data, but I can't seem to figure out how to tell the LXML parser to not do any HTML entity conversion for me. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is the parser class? you can disable entities resolving by setting `resolve_entities` arg to `False`, like in   ETCompatXMLParser,   XMLParser or XMLTreeBuilder.

Comment: I'm just using `lxml.etree.tostring()`, which doesn't have an option for `resolve_entities` by the look of it. I'm essentially taking the tree and outputting with `pretty_print=True` so I can hand it off to another module which will save the new file somewhere. Do those other parsers allow for nice formatting like lxml does?

Comment: I guess the real issue is that when I want to write or print the xml tree as a string, it always gives me the entities with no option to change this.

Comment: The challenge is that the output you want isn't xml, so the "xml" method won't work, but you want to keep tags, so its not "text" either. You could do this with an XSLT stylesheet that uses a text output method but where you still write out the tags and attributes. I'd suggest a search for "xslt pretty print xml document".

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`etree.Entity`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#Entity) to create entities that are then serialized properly.

Here's a very 'simple' example - real world uses would usually require more complicated operations (well, you're dealing with XML):

```
>>> from lxml import etree, html
>>> element = etree.fromstring('<p>Hel-lo World</p>')
>>> parts = element.text.split('-')
>>> element.text = parts[0]
>>> shy = etree.Entity('shy')
>>> shy.tail = parts[1]
>>> element.append(shy)
>>> html.tostring(element, encoding='unicode')
'<p>Hel&shy;lo World</p>'
```